# Apex (apex.run) installation issues

Tags: apex-framework

I want to install [Apex](https://github.com/apex/apex) (similar to the [Serverless Framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless)) on a Windows 7 machine. I have followed the steps for installation at [apex.run](http://apex.run/). After installing the binary file downloaded from apex.run, it shows the usage commands.
But when I try to run any command, its giving me error saying

> apex is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have also setup AWS CLI configuration and it works.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used windows (32-bit) also. for AWS & apex both, after installation, I had to update the environment variables before it worked everywhere.. previously they both worked only from the folder in which they were installed.

1. go to start menu
2. write 'edit environment variables for your account' (without the quotes of course)
3. select the path variable and enter the location(s) of the AWS.EXE file and the APEX.EXE file at the end of your existing PATH variable

   C:\Ruby24\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI;C:\apex_1.0.0-rc2_windows_386
4. close all command prompts windows
5. open a new cmd window
6. now 'apex init' or 'apex deploy' etc should run as intended